# Digitar um valor com "." ponto. Ex: 7.5

Tags: java

Boa noite, eu comecei a utilizar o JAVA a pouco tempo, queria saber como faço para o usuário poder digitar o valor com "." ponto. Caso alguém puder ajudar, agradeço desde já!!

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
public static void main (String[] args){

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Entre com o numero de notas");
  int quantidadeNotas = sc.nextInt();

  int notas[] = new int[quantidadeNotas];

  for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeNotas; i++){
  System.out.println ("Entre com a nota " + (i+1));
  notas[i] = sc.nextInt();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeNotas; i++){
  System.out.println (notas[i]);
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: *"como faço para o usuário poder digitar o valor com ".""* não pode "obrigar" o usuário a digitar, mas pode validar e pedir para digitar novamente, agora nem adianta fazer isso se está lendo um inteiro, inteiro não tem ponto `nextInt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa já deixar essa pergunta inútil, nem todos sabem de muito em programação. Ele é um Novo Contribuidor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Entre com o numero de notas: ");
        int quantidadeNotas = sc.nextInt();

        double notas[] = new double[quantidadeNotas];

        for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeNotas; i++){
            System.out.println ("Entre com a nota [" + (i+1) + "]: ");
            notas[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeNotas; i++){
            System.out.println (notas[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Fiz um ajuste e na hora de colocar a nota com decimal coloque ",".
10,0 assim.

> "como faço para o usuário poder digitar o valor com "."" não pode "obrigar" o usuário a digitar, mas pode validar e pedir para digitar novamente, agora nem adianta fazer isso se está lendo um inteiro, inteiro não tem ponto nextInt – Ricardo Pontual 5 horas atrás

Pode não obrigar mas sim fazer um controle de validação. Além disso dependendo da linguagem de país, EUA usa "." e Brasil usa ",". Por exemplo se colocar apenas 6, podemos fazer uma transformação para 6.0.
Tudo é em seu tempo. Ok?

Comment: "Tanto Faz é um usuário novo. Seja gentil ao pedir esclarecimentos, comentar, e responder".

Comment: "*EUA usa "." e Brasil usa ","*" - você pode definir se o `Scanner` vai aceitar vírgula ou ponto, bastando setar o *locale*, veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/MspF8x) e [aqui](https://ideone.com/sSqgya) - se não definir um *locale*, ele usa o *default* que está configurado na JVM